# Unable to re-map certain keys with CompizConfig

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, media-buttons

Modern keyboards come with a bunch of crap and useless buttons but often few media keys.

My current one has play/pause, vol +/- and calculator only.

I would like to remap the `XF86Calculator` button to be "next track" but it just keeps bringing up the calculator as normal. The next track button is not pressed.

I have one successful mapping which sets the `Pause` button to trigger the command `xdotool key XF86AudioPlay`

Some others will work `XF86Back`, `insert`, letter keys.

I cannot remap some keys to the exact same operations, including the calculator button. I am using the key capture function so I know the XF86 code is correct

Any ideas?

Comment: By "calculator", did you mean "numpad", or it is really a calculator button?

Comment: It's a calculator button `XF86Calculator`

Comment: Have you tried going into `System Settings` - `keyboard` - `shortcuts`  and to disable the calculator there first before trying to re-define it???  Please feed back so I can convert this to an answer...  ;-)

Comment: That worked at first. Now any of the keys I edit in the keyboard editor break permanently. I have rebooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very much a workaround but I have instead used compizconfig to map these keys to CLI commands for banshee rather than trying to use the media keys.

Works 100% in banshee therefore but no use if you're using other media players.